# Semireflectivity of a material (acrylic)

Tags: reflection, optical-materials

I am using acrylic for a project due to its semi-reflectivity (as well as the fact its easily laser cut, and is in great supply where I am). However, I was wondering about the factors that determine the reflectivity of a material, and what I can do to enhance it. What I mean by the first part of the statement is that I wish to see if there is any way to analyze a material, and determine its reflectivity (i.e. ratio of incident light to intensity of light reflected) with some sort of equation(s) or law(s). Additionally, I wish to see what I should vary to enhance its semi-reflectivity, as well as anything I may add (a layer of a substance on top) WITHOUT compromising its transparency (to a reasonable degree).

Answer (score 0):

Reflectivity is governed by the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) which show that reflectivity of a dielectric material depends on the refractive index mismatch between the two media, the angle of incidence, and the polarization of the light.

In principle, a thin coating of a material (with intermediate refractive index to reduce reflectivity, or with higher refractive index to increase it) can be used to change this - but it's rather a hard thing to do yourself.